# How to open an html file in web browser using python after I have logged in?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome

I have coded a log in system and when you've logged in I want it to open a html file in chrome.
I have tried:

```
import webbrowser
import os
print()
f = open('code.html','w')
filename = 'file:///'+os.getcdw()+'/' + 'code.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab('code.html')
```

but it has not worked.
Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Why do you need to open the file `code.html` in write mode?

Answer (score 0):

the code 
`import web-browser import OS print() f = open('code.html','w') filename = 'file:///'+os.getcdw()+'/' + 'code.html' webbrowser.open_new_tab('code.html')`
wouldent work. You are trying to open it not just print it, try calling it like you would a javascript file that might work.